# Cauchy-Schwarz type formula for positive integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\gamma(x,y)$ be some complex valued function in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ such that
$$
\gamma(x,y)=\overline{\gamma(y,x)},\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}
$$ Let $S=(1-\Delta)^{1/2}$ acting on $\gamma$. If we know that
$$
\forall f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}), \int f(z)(\int \gamma(x,z)f(x)dx)dz>0
$$
Then can we conclude that
$$
|S(\gamma)(x,y)|^{2}\le S(\gamma)(x,x)S(\gamma)(y,y),\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}
$$ from some spectral type argument? If $\gamma(x,y)$ is a positive semi-definite Hermitian matrix, then this should be easy ($l^{2}$ instead of $L^{2}$ case). But for $L^{2}$ I do not know how to prove it.

My thought is we have
$$
|S\gamma(x,y)|^{2}=\int S(\gamma)(x,y)S(\gamma)(y,x)dxdy=\int \gamma(x,y)(1-\Delta)\gamma(y,x)dxdy
$$
but this does not seem to be helpful at all. The main difficulty I have is $S\gamma$ should be a positive, Hermitian and self-adjoint integral operator. But here we are not integrating it against anything, and I do not know how to make use of its properties.

Comment: Awesome profile page there, Bombyx.

Comment: I asked this on MO yesterday, hopefully the problem is resolved now.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a "Cauchy-Schwarz type formula"? Or "Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz type inequality"? The "Schwarz" doesn't stand for Laurent Schwarz, but Hermann Schwarz http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Amandus_Schwarz ...

Comment: Btw, to see the MO post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/172266/cauchy-schwarz-type-formula-for-positive-integral-operator